# Inserting an element in a std::vector before element of certain value

Tags: c++

Can you suggest a nicer way of inserting a value before another value in an std::vector:

```
template<class T>
void insert(std::vector<T>& container, const T& valueToInsertBefore, const T& valueToInsert)
{
    std::vector<T>::iterator i = container.begin();
    std::vector<T>::iterator end = container.end();
    for(;i!=end;++i)
    {
        if(*i==valueToInsertBefore)
        {
            i = container.insert(i, valueToInsert); 
            i++;                                
            end = container.end();                  
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

Should insert for each instance of valueToInsertBefore found in the std::vector.

Comment: use `std::find` and insert it before the iterator returned by `std::find`

Comment: @Tony The Lion What if valueToInsertBefore occurs multiple times in the vector?

Comment: @I guess you'll have to write a `find_every` that uses `std::find` to find and insert your item before `valueToInsertBefore` until the value you're looking to insert it before no longer occurs in the respective container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to locate the value instead of the explicit loop:

```
std::vector<T>::iterator i = v.begin();
while (v.end() != (i = std::find(i, v.end(), valueToInsertBefore)))
{
    // insert() returns an iterator to the inserted element.
    // The '+ 2' moves past it and the searched for element.
    //
    i = v.insert(i, valueToInsert) + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` may turn out to be rather inefficient due to the needed reallocations in case it's rather large and/or the element to be inserted before appears very often. A more simplistic approach using a copy like this might turn out to be more CPU-friendly (at the expense of requiring more memory):

```
template<class T>
void insert(std::vector<T>& container,
            const T& valueToInsertBefore,
            const T& valueToInsert)
{
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve( container.size() );

    std::vector<T>::const_iterator it, end = container.end();
    for ( it = container.begin(); it != end; ++it ) {
        if ( *it == valueToInsertBefore ) {
            result.push_back( valueToInsert );
        }
        result.push_back( *it );
    }

    container.swap( result );
}
```

Comment: Depending on the expected performance of `operator==`, it might also be better to count the instances of `valueToInsertBefore` in order to `reserve` the right amount of space. This code is "optimized" for the case where either nothing is inserted (so that the original reserve is enough), or else any insertions come in less than some kind of "rounding up" that the vector implementation does when increasing capacity. Otherwise you're going to get one reallocation (approximately as costly as a pass to count the number of insertions) and you might even get more than one.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Right - in fact, it not only depends on the expected performance of `operator==` but also on the expected average length of the lists as well as the expected number of items to be inserted... sheesh, a lot of expectations. :-]

Comment: I like this answer anyway, I didn't intend to talk it down. I just mention that as another thing to try out if performance is critical, see whether it helps. To be positive: this answer doesn't even necessarily use more memory than the questioner's, since if the questioner's reallocates then it uses about as much as this one does if it *doesn't* reallocate.

Answer (score 1):

```
container.insert(std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), valueToInsertBefore), valueToInsert);
```

Comment: What if valueToInsertBefore occurs multiple times in the vector?

Comment: @Baz, The above is *exactly* the same as your solution (NOTE: how you terminate your loop on the first find - well this is *exactly* what the above does)

Comment: ...with the added bonus that an item is inserted at the end even if the matching item is not found...

Comment: @other_downvoters, kind of harsh to downvote a solution (to the original problem), based on an update by the OP which changes the nature of the question...

Comment: I'm not going to bother downvoting, but the questioner's edit didn't change the code (unless the code was changed within the edit window and then the text was changed later). So that's what you get for assuming the questioner meant "the first instance of another value" when in fact he meant something different and his code did something different ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You better change container, lists are better for this kind of operations. With an insert you are risking to invalidate iterators and pointers and you also need memory reallocations.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/insert/

Comment: This operation is not very commonly executed for my container so at the moment I will stick with std::vector

Comment: @Baz you shouldn't use linked lists anyway!!! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340797/Number-crunching-Why-you-should-never-ever-EVER-us

Comment: @enobayram Yes, I've heard linked list should only be used in very specific circumstances - if even then.